# Pillow throws error on save with StringIO

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, stringio, bytesio

In some tutorials was explained to use `StringIO` in Pillow save method. but when I use this testcode:

```
from PIL import Image
from io import StringIO, BytesIO

photo = Photo.objects.get(pk=1)
bytes = BytesIO()
string = StringIO()

image = Image.open(photo.image)
image.save(string, 'PNG')
```

then I get the error:

> string argument expected, got 'bytes'

But when I use `BytesIO` like this:

```
image.save(bytes, 'PNG')
```

it works fine. That is strange, because the error message says that a string is expected and bytes is wrong, but obviously the opposite is correct. And that is also contrary to the informations I got while checking tutorials.

Maybe the behavior of `save()` was changed in the Pillow fork, and the error message was not updated? Or is it different because I use Python 3 with `io` module instead of `StringIO` module?

---

edit, examples where `StringIO` is proposed

- [How do you convert a PIL `Image` to a Django `File`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723220/how-do-you-convert-a-pil-image-to-a-django-file)
- https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/10473/
- [Django - Rotate image and save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37150890/django-rotate-image-and-save)

Comment: It is probably just a mistake in the tutorial. I don't know why would they save as image as a string with StringIO when it should be saved with BytesIO to be readable by image readers. It is meant to be used with BytesIO.

Comment: I was also confused about that, but my interpretation was, that `save()` expects a filepath as string and you can trick it with using presenting this StringIO object. Actually, the errormessage says that a string should be provided. There is for example this (first) answer that advises to use StringIO (but for PIL): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723220/how-do-you-convert-a-pil-image-to-a-django-file

Comment: I suspect that this is a just Python version issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646286/python-pil-how-to-write-png-image-to-string

Comment: but then the error message is still wrong, or do I misunderstand it?